# Unable to get actionscript to load xml file then loop

Tags: actionscript-3, xml-parsing, flash-cs5

I have spent many hours searching the internet and have come up empty handed. My problem is that i am trying to create a flash file that loops every 10 seconds and changes 2 dynamic text fields each time it loops.

```
   var xmlData:XML = new XML();
   var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("shout.xml");
   var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);

   function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
   {
    xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);

 show_txt.text = xmlData.SERVERTITLE;
 song_txt.text = xmlData.SONGTITLE;

   }
```

The dynamic fields are set correctly and are all in the same scene but as i said, it does not load the right fields and when it does work it caches which i do not want it to do.

Comment: Could you post the shout.xml content and the wrong text in show_txt and song_txt?

Comment: Where in your code is the event listener for the URLLoader being added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe set a "counter" variable that increments and append your URL with `shout.xml?c=[counter]`